# URLs design for filtering Model's attributes in Django

Tags: django, http, url

Need you advice.

In my Django app I have a model for some Users. Users have some attributes: name, age, phone etc. This is not the API site. Just my intranet user's catalog.

I can get users using the following URLs:

```
/users/   # All users
/users/12 # User with ID 12
```

But how should I design URLs to get only the users which meet certain criteria? Is it a good practice to use query string for that purpose? Like this:

```
/users/                    # All users
/users/?name=John          # Filter by name
/users/?name=Peter&age=25  # Filter by name AND age
```

Comment: while `GET` parameters work, you have more control with URLs. Example: `/users/<username>/<age>/` could be a URL pattern, and django would throw a 404 if this condition is not met, rather than you manually checking it in the view.

Comment: @karthikr: the point here is to _filter_ the users list, not to display details for a specific user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the point is to display the same object list just filtered / sorted on a specific criteria (or set of) then yes, that's one of the purpose of query strings.

Comment: Yes, the same type of objects (users), just not all of them but filtered.

Comment: @Lufa: then you have your answer.